# Disable anchor (a) tag tooltip

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to remove the red circle, it always shows on the bottom of the browser (No jQuery)
[image: example]

Comment: Pretty sure you're looking at a browser-level and/or OS-level feature that you won't have access to in the browser API...

Comment: There's only one kind of site I can think of that would try to do that: scam sites. They want you to click things without being able to check where you're being sent.

Comment: @Ouroborus I wanted to make a rickroll lmao

Answer (score 1):

Remove the href="whatever" from the link and open the link by calling a function. This completely removes the link preview on the bottom left of the page.

HTML:

```
<a (click)="openUrl('https://google.com')">
```

JS:

```
 openUrl(url: string): void {
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From [@Md Atiqur Rahman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16432482/md-atiqur-rahman) I added some code and make this:

```js
const a_tags = document.querySelectorAll("a");

books.forEach((element) => {
    const href = element.href;
    element.removeAttribute("href");
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        openUrl(href);
    });
});

function openUrl(url) {
    window.open(url);
}
```